# Does Angular API only call requested data?

Tags: c#, angular, api

I am making an api call and want make sure I am reducing data transfer as much as possible.

on the Angular end I have a request:

```
http.get<RecordSummary>(url)
```

Where `RecordSummary` is:

```
export interface RecordSummary
{
    Id: number;
    Name: string;   
}
```

Now my API endpoint retuns a `Full Record`:

```
public class FulLRecord {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When I make the call, does the entire Full Record get transferred over the call or just the requested fields? My understanding so far is that it is the full record, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: An arbitrary web API sends whatever it sends. Unless you are passing some information to that API that tells it that you want only the x, y, z fields (and this type of query is supported by that API -- e.g. APIS that support odata), the entire item that the API says it returns will be transmitted, because it has no information to tell it to return less.

Comment: I agree Paul. Your endpoint pretty sure has no clue about your interface, not even about your `FullRecord`-class. In fact it just returns something which is *mapped* to a `FullRecord`on the client-side. So it just returns its own representation of your objects, that may match your `FullRecord`, however chances are that type has even more properties than your `FullRecord`, and even more than your `RecordSummary`. However without knowing your endpoint it's hard to help you any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make this call:

```js
http.get<RecordSummary>(url)
```

You're specifying that you want to deserialize the JSON you receive and use it as a `RecordSummary` object. It does not communicate this object structure to the API, so you will still be receiving the full object that the API sends.

You can confirm this by looking at the network request in your browser's developer tools window. For Chrome you can open this by pressing F12.

Please also note that you're dealing with TypeScript which still gets converted to JavaScript when you "build" it, so although your statically typed code has a `RecordSummary` object, the actual object in-memory will have more data in it if the API sent more. You can observe this by casting it to `any` and then accessing one of the properties:

```js
let result = http.get<RecordSummary>(url);
let fullObject = <any>result;
alert(fullObject.Age);
```

This will show an alert with the Age that was received from the API.